# record/upload videos from my site to YouTube with unlisted privacy

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

is there is a way to record video and audio from my site and upload it to YouTube then sit its privacy to ( either public , unlisted or private ) from my site , without having to go to YouTube and change the sittings of every video

** so far i have managed to record video and audio from my site and share it on YouTube , but its by default set to public , i wanted to be unlisted so no one can view it anywhere else but only from my site through the embedded link , could anyone help me with that ?**

```
                        $message .= '<script>
                                            var tag = document.createElement("script");
                                            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                                            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                                            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
                                            var widget;
                                            var player;
                                            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                                                widget = new YT.UploadWidget("widget", {
                                                    width: 400,
                                                    events: {
                                                        "onUploadSuccess": onUploadSuccess,
                                                        "onProcessingComplete": onProcessingComplete,
                                                        "onApiReady": onApiReady
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            function onUploadSuccess(event) {
                                                $("#loading").css("display","block");
                                                $("#response").val("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+event.data.videoId);
                                            }
                                            function onProcessingComplete(event) {
                                                $("#widget").css("display","none");
                                                $("#loading").css("display","none");
                                                $(".questionRespondButton").css("display","block");
                                                player = new YT.Player("player", {
                                                    height: 300,
                                                    width: 400,
                                                    videoId: event.data.videoId,
                                                    events: {}
                                                });
                                            }

                                        </script>';
```

Comment: The code samples for the Javascript API have the privacy settings in the example here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

Comment: i added the script that i have right now , i checked the your link but i am not sure if its going to work with my script , please check my script that i have just added